# .bat file calling .vbs in logon script not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory, winlogon

Users in our domain are configured for the ad user profile logon script function.

We used to have a .vbs file being executed at logon which worked fine.

Since we changed the default program for .vbs extensions to notepad.exe instead of cscript (security reasons) that vbs file is no longer properly executed at startup.

My initial thought was replacing that .vbs with a .bat file that just calls the .vbs using cscript.exe which should look like that.

```
@echo off
start cscript startup.vbs
```

when i fire this locally it works fine, but as soon as i put it up on the domain controller it didnt work at first. so i changed the path of the .vbs to the full name of the network location like this.

```
@echo off
start cscript \\%logonserver%\netlogon\startup.vbs
```

%logonserver% just stands for the variable assigned to the domain controller that user ends up.

when i navigate to that folder with a domain user on a machine and start the .bat file it works.

i then changed the name of the file in the ad user profile logon script to the .bat file and rebooted my machine.

nothing happens at startup so i ended up clueless.

anyone has any ideas for this?

thanks in advance.
regards stefan

Comment: Quote the path. Why are you using the `start` command?

Comment: i think u need start when u want to name your window no? so in the end it looked like that `start cscript "LogonScript" %logonserver%\script.vbs`

Comment: i tried using the .lnk file and it seems to work fine now, sadly its still opening a cmd window and all i can achieve is make it minimizd but not completely hidden which would be preferred.